# how to store values of treeview into database using asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I am working on a news portal in asp.net. In that I have used a treeview for showing all the Categories of news. I have used following code to insert News category into sql server databse:

```
foreach (TreeNode node in TreeView1.CheckedNodes)
{                     
    long NewsCategory = Convert.ToInt64(node.Value);
    long NewsID = News_ID;
    int rt1 = new Process_NewsCategory().insert(objNewsCategory);
}
```

But it is showing error:

> -Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the code below:

```
foreach (TreeNode node in TreeView1.CheckedNodes.ToList())
{
   long NewsCategory = Convert.ToInt64(node.Value);
   long NewsID = News_ID;
   int rt1 = new Process_NewsCategory().insert(objNewsCategory);
}
```

Comment: there is not any function like ToList() showing in the treeview.it is showing error SystemWeb.UI.WebControls does not Contaon any definition of ToList

Comment: Convert your TreeView1.CheckedNode in to the IList Collection. IList<TreeNode> nodes = new List<TreeNode>();
    foreach( TreeNode node in TreeView1.Nodes )
{
        if( node.Nodes.Count > 0 )
          nodes.Add( node );
}

Comment: How i should convert CheckNodes in to the IList Collection

Comment: Instead of using foreach use for loop like : TreeNodeCollection checkedNodeCollection = TreeView1.CheckedNodes;  for(int i=0;i<checkedNodeCollection.Count;i++)
{
    Treenode checkedNode = checkedNodeCollection[i]; 
    .... 
    ..  
}

Comment: when i starting tracing the debug this error is occuring after inserting into databse. when i started to all checked node false using code:                                                            foreach (TreeNode node in TreeView1.CheckedNodes)
            {
                //objNewsCategory.Category = Convert.ToInt64(node.Value);
                node.Checked = false;
            } then it is showing error

Comment: try with the for loop approach.